# Does phantomjs support Bayeux or WebSockets?

Tags: websocket, phantomjs, faye, bayeux

Just simple question, because I didn't find any references in docs..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a simple answer: PhantomJS 1.x does not, but PhantomJS 2 does support websockets.

Modernizr output for PhantomJS 2.0.0:

[image]