# Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: wss://* != ws://*

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, websocket, phantomjs

when i run MeteorJS(1.1.0.2) test in PhantomJS(1.9.8) get this error msg in Amazone AWS

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: wss://ddp--5539-torrentz.meteor.com/sockjs/102/chvlh52p/websocket != ws://ddp--5539-torrentz.meteor.com/sockjs/102/chvlh52p/websocket
```

& this prevent all MeteorJS Mongo DB operations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does phantomjs support Bayeux or WebSockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827361/does-phantomjs-support-bayeux-or-websockets)

Comment: the same script with same conf  have no error in my MAC

Comment: So, share your code.

Answer (score 1):

solved with upgrade phantomjs 1.9.8 to 2.0 in ubuntu