# Flex on PhantomJS

Tags: css, phantomjs, flexbox

does PhantomJS support modern flex? if I run this file:

```
$ cat x.js
var $ = require('jquery');
$('<div/>', {id: 'x'}).appendTo($('body'));
var x = $('#x');
x.css('color', 'red');
console.log('color: ' + x.css('color'));
x.css('flex', '0 0 0px');
console.log('css: ' + x.css('flex'));
```

one can see that `.css()` works fine for colour but not for flex.

```
$ phantomjs x.js
color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
css: undefined
```

I've also tried some of the variants: `-webkit-flex`, `-moz-box-flex` and `-ms-flex`, all of which yield the same results.  curiously, `-webkit-box-flex` returns `0` instead of `undefined`, but that seems wrong.

I'm running with:

```
$ phantomjs --version
1.9.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the PhantomJS 1.x engine is now more than 5 years old. Yes, flexbox is not supported. Modernizr reports that flexboxlegacy is supported. With PhantomJS 2.x you get [support for flex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28827509/1816580).

Comment: well... it took some doing to get v2 installed on OSX.  the npm version didn't work but fortunately the home-brew version works (I'm now on 2.1.1) and yes! it supports flex.  yea!!

Comment: I'd say **limited** flex support. Turns out centering doesn't work properly: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12367

Comment: Using the early spec syntax works on 2.1.1, for issues such as centering. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/